Issues with Dart Sass
Has anyone figured out how to disable Dart SASS from throwing errors in --watch mode using Live Server in VS Code? I've just started using SASS and while I'm typing out CSS in a SASS file, for example if I'm beginning to type out a variable $ the page goes blank and it says "Error: Expected identifier" and it's really annoying and choppy to have these "errors" which aren't errors keep coming up.
I've tried all the flags that Dart SASS offers, like --no-stop-on-error and --no-error-css to no avail. Has anyone else fixed this problem/annoyance?
CLI error that comes up
